# rerouting a normal phone call to skype

Tags: networking, skype, telephony, telecommunication, yahoo-messenger

I am a mobile/web developer but Im trying to see if there is any way this is possible:
Rerouting an incoming telephone call to skype or any other voice chat application?

Can anyone explain what technologies/ APIs are available to do something like this?

Thanks

Apologize if this question is broad or out of context here. Please let me know where to post if so.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SipToSis](http://www.mhspot.com/sts/siptosis.html). This will not only solve the problem (GPL licensed out-of-the-box working product), but most of all studying it will help you understand the APIs used.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tip :). Any more names/ideas that do similar things?

Comment: I had a similar problem - and I eneded the search there, as this was what I needed. Everything else I found sucked one or the other way.